# Java Stacks Interface: IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java

For my CS class, I had to code a Stacks interface extending off of LinkedList. However, there is an error in my peek() method apparently. When I implement this into one of my other programs, I return an IndexOutOfBounds exception (Index 0; Size 0) and I cannot seem to find what exception or statement that would handle that for me in my peek() method.

```
    public class MyStack<anyType> extends LinkedList<anyType> {
    private ArrayList<anyType> list;

    public MyStack() {
        list = new ArrayList<anyType>(10);
    }

    public void push(anyType x) {
        list.add(0, x);
    }
    public anyType pop() {
        if (list.get(0) == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            anyType x = list.get(0);
            list.remove(0);
            return x;
        }
    }
    public anyType peek() {
      if (list.get(0) == null) {
         return null;
      } else {
         anyType x = list.get(0);
           return x;
      }
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (list.size() == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your data structure is a little messed up. You extended `LinkedList` but your structure also contains an `ArrayList` even if the stack methods work properly if someone calls the other methods you can have unintended results happen. This doesn't help your bug just an overall observation.

Comment: You simply can't call get(0) on a list that is empty, because 0 is not a valid index for an empt list Read the javadoc of the classes and methods you use: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-

Comment: You are trying to get the 0th element when it doesn't exist which causes your index out of bounds. Don't you have another method to check if any elements exist or not?

Comment: are you sure you're meant to [extend](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) it? and not use [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before checking if list.get(0) == null you need to check if the list even exists at that index. Use: `

```
if(list.size() <= 0 || list.get(0) == null) 
return null
```

Comment: why would you need to check if list.get(0) is null? shouldn't checking for size be enough? and what's wrong with [List.isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty())?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do, A list can be full of null values which doesn't effect its size. List.isEmpty() would work fine its doing the same thing.

Comment: yes, but why wouldn't the code work even if list would be full of null values, without the check? Wouldn't it anyway return null, with or without a null value check?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're only getting this error when you have no items in your stack. If you have no items in your stack, then your stack will have no indexes and calling list.get(0) won't make sense.

You'll need to handle the case of an empty stack with no indexes:

```
if (list.size() == 0) return null;
```

Of course, this is assuming "list" itself isn't null. A much better way to do this would be to create a separate method checking a list of class invariants that include things like null references, empty stacks, etc. But for the purposes of a simple assignment this will suffice.